# JQuery .click function based on button id contains partial text

Tags: jquery, button, selector

In my web app, a text tag, `updateTender` is embedded in each of several buttons, all with a different prefix & suffix for later use.  What is the Jquery code to begin the function upon button click, matched on id contains some text?

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
$("[id*='updateTender']").click(function(){
alert("clicked!");
});
```

but get no alert response/button is unresponsive.

example button html:

```
<button id='1._updateTender__.14'>Update</button>
```

Comment: You can use a class to group your buttons and upon clicked you can use this keyword to access Dom element i.e. to access id on jQuery click handler

Comment: i have run your code it's  working fine . did you add `jquery cdn` ,also does your console have any error ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. Make sure you have added [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/download/) in your project.

```js
$("[id*='updateTender']").click(function(){
  alert("clicked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='1._updateTender__.14'>Update</button>
```